# @media only screen and (max-device-width) images width and height definition

Tags: html, css, image, layout, height

I have a problem with width and height of images on the smartphone. I use this code. But I don't know why on the smartphone it also uses the same height of 13em like on desktop screen. All other amartphone definitions work fine.

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 60em) {
    /* STYLES HERE for DEVICES with physical max-screen width of 60em */
    article img {
        float: left;
        margin-right: 0.2em;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
    }

    article img {
        float: left;
        margin-right: 0.2em;
        height: 13em;
    }
```

Comment: Because you set the height to 13em outside the mediaquery - so it is applied to all devices

Comment: move article ima{} block to the top of @media block

Comment: also make sure to put the media query at the bottom of your css file - css code is read from top to bottom, so any code below your media query will be prioritized, unless the code inside the media query has higher specifity

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the media query under the article img.
Not related but you don't need to repeat float and margin-right since you're not overriding them.